# cron in windows 10 permission and xampp setup

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

I am trying to send email using PHP mailer at regular interval. I am using windows 10 and have set up a cron . Here is *.bat* file  code .

```
@echo off
schtasks /Create /TN XAMPP /TR "C:/xampp/php/php-win.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/aurr/emailcron.php" /SC MINUTE /MO 1
pause
```

Problem is  even though I am able to send emails ,there is no attachment in received emails .But when i manually execute emailcron.php  ,I get attachment in received email.My guess is this might be because of permission issue .How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

When the script is run by the cron task it's run by whichever user the cron script is run as (a default if you don't override it), and when you run it yourself it's obviously run as you. If you have permission to read the file but the cron user does not, it won't be able to send the file.
Several things to look at here:

- Run the cron task as a user that does have permission to read the
  files, e.g. you.
- Give the cron user permission to read the files.
- Make your script check for a successful return value when it adds
  attachments.

For the last of these, do it like this:

```
if (!$mail->addAttachment('path\to\file')) {
    echo "Could not access path\to\file";
    exit;
}
```

That way it will generate an error and not send the message if it can't access the file, rather than failing silently as it's doing at present.